# Unable to see the "save to disk" button

Tags: javascript, downloadify

I am trying to include downloadify javascript+flash plugin on my web page but somehow the "Save to disk" button is not visible.

Working demo :http://pixelgraphics.us/downloadify/test.html

my page: http://www.javaexperience.com/Feedback/index.html

can someone point me to what I could be missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that your path to the `swf` or `image` assets are wrong.

From the github page:

```
swf: ‘media/downloadify.swf’ Required 
Path to the SWF File. Can be relative from the page, or an absolute path.

downloadImage: ‘images/download.png’ Required 
Path to the Button Image. Can be relative from the page or an absolute path.
```

Your example exactly copies the working example for those paths.

yours:

```
media/downloadify.swf
queue_name=downloadify_1361560979222&width=100&height=30&downloadImage=images/download.png
```

Theirs:

```
media/downloadify.swf
queue_name=downloadify_1361561050132&width=100&height=30&downloadImage=images/download.png
```

I am betting that those assets are not located in the same place on your server. Otherwise your download object is there and should be working.